# How to Logout of AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

1. How does one log out of AskUbuntu?
2. Or is there only logging in?

I've searched each time I've been on and not a logout button or direction or hint to be found.
I've looked through the Help Center.
There are no hints anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Top right on the browser window I have a Stack Exchange option

[image]

Clicking on it shows a logout option top right, where I only need to click on the "log out" option.  It asks for confirmation which allows me to logout, or cancel logout if I changed my mind.

Comment: Hey @guiverc. In the last line change `I` to `You`. I can't edit it, unfortunately.